Длина строки в с++
string a = "HELLO";
const char* b = a.c_str();
cout << sizeof(b);

Почему-то выводит 8, хотя должно 6

Выводит размер указателя. Может, вам пригодится strlen?

Не 6, а 5. Не sizeof, а a.size().

Это происходит потому что размер указателя не зависит от размера объекта, на который они указывает. Его размер зависит от  разрядности операционной системы. В 64-битной системе размер указателя как раз составляет 8 байт
